# C++ function in separate file not working

Tags: c++, function, include

I have a problem and I apologise in advance for what may be an amateurish question, but I am trying to include a function from a separate C++ file, and I'm getting errors.

Here is the main code (well, the important parts):

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#include "/remote/cronin/jdagosti/Contour/shuffle.cc"

int main() {

  vector<double> JD;
  vector<double> zenith_deg;
  vector<double> azimuth_deg;
  vector<double> JD_sh;
  vector<double> zen_sh;
  vector<double> az_sh;

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){

    cout << JD[i] << endl;

  }

  shuffle(JD,zenith_deg,azimuth_deg,JD_sh,zen_sh,az_sh);

  cout << " " << endl;

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){

    cout << JD_sh[i] << endl;

  }

}
```

and here is the shuffle function I have (in a separate .cc file):

```
void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){

  vector<int> array;

  for(int j = 0; j < JD.size(); ++j){

    array.push_back(0);

  }

  int index;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for(int i = 0; i < JD.size(); ++i){

    index = floor(JD.size() * rand() / RAND_MAX);

    if(array.at(index) == 1){

      i -= 1;
      continue;

    } else {

      array.at(index) = 1;

      JD_sh.push_back(JD[index]);

    }

  }

}
```

and these are the errors I am getting:

```
shuffle.cc:6:14: error: variable or field ‘shuffle’ declared void
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
              ^
shuffle.cc:6:14: error: ‘vector’ was not declared in this scope
shuffle.cc:6:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
                     ^
shuffle.cc:6:33: error: ‘vector’ was not declared in this scope
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
                                 ^
shuffle.cc:6:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
                                        ^
shuffle.cc:6:56: error: ‘vector’ was not declared in this scope
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
                                                        ^
shuffle.cc:6:63: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
                                                               ^
shuffle.cc:6:80: error: ‘vector’ was not declared in this scope
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
                                                                                ^
shuffle.cc:6:87: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
                                                                                       ^
shuffle.cc:6:102: error: ‘vector’ was not declared in this scope
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
                                                                                                      ^
shuffle.cc:6:109: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
                                                                                                             ^
shuffle.cc:6:125: error: ‘vector’ was not declared in this scope
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
                                                                                                                             ^
shuffle.cc:6:132: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
 void shuffle(vector<double> JD, vector<double> zenith, vector<double> azimuth, vector<double> JD_sh, vector<double> zen_sh, vector<double> az_sh){
```

So it's not recognising the headers in the main code, and I guarantee you they are both located in the same folder. Also, I know it's bad practice to 'include' a .cc file rather than a header, but I'm not too familiar with doing that and anyway, I have definitely seen this work before. I was under the impression that including that .cc file containing the function is equivalent to placing it right there, so it should definitely be recognising the earlier code. One thing I have noticed is that the error is referring to 'shuffle.cc' rather than what it usually says, something along the lines of 'from file located in Maps.cc...', perhaps this has something to do with it? In any case I'm stumped, thanks in advance for any help!

Joshua

Comment: Is there anything preceding `shuffle()` in shuffle.cc?

Comment: You need to `#include <vector>` in the `cc` file too

Comment: `#include "/remote/cronin/jdagosti/Contour/shuffle.cc"` don't include source files. Use `std::vector<>`. I'd suspect the errors occur when your build system tries to compile `shuffle.cc`  standalone.

Comment: What compilation command are you using?

Comment: @CoryKramer He doesn't need to do that if he's `#include`ing it in the main program.

Comment: Imho you question is ok, but the code in it looks dirty. If your quesiton would be closed or downvoted, I suggest to ask it again, but without the dirty part (for example, include the shuffle.cc into the place of your very dirty `#include`).

Comment: @Barmar He does though if the compiler is compiling the .cc file in the project.

Comment: Mark shuffle.cc to be not compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are actually compiling the `shuffle.cc` file besides including it. *If* you persist on including the source file then don't compile it as well.

*Or...*

Don't include the source file, and let the source file be compiled and linked the standard way, but then you need to include the proper header files in the source file.

---

On a side-note, your program will have *undefined behavior* when you fix the compilation errors. You access the `JD` vector out of bounds. Or at least it looks likes that, it might be that you fill it in the parts you deem unimportant. The problem with that is that it will look like you have more problems than you actually have. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your future questions.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was doing, I knew it was a stupid error! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you include some file to your project, you are not copying the text of the file to your main file (like in JavaScript does), first-of-all the compiler will compile every single file separate, and then will link them together, so when your call the "shuffle.cc" file, you will link the compiled version of "shuffle.cc", and not the plain text, and when it compiles there is no conection with main.cpp, so you need to include all includes and namespaces again

so just add:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

and should work

P.S: don't forget to include the , i know that in some IDE, like Visual Studio, will compile without any problem, but won't work for every compiler